# Logger callback and Router requests causing SQL Server concurrency issues in Express

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I have a express server that handles queries on a SQL Server server database. For my logs, I am logging all requests that are received into a logs table:

```js
const morgan = require('morgan')
const stream = require('stream')
const DatabaseController = require('./dbcontroller')

const databaseStream = new stream.Writable()

// anything that is logged is passed to this stream... the text is logged
databaseStream.write = async (text) => {
  await DatabaseController.addLog({ text })
}
// remove the img binary from the body - which is too large

const logger = morgan( 'tiny', { immediate: true, stream: databaseStream })

module.exports = logger
```

Additionally, there are some requests that can be made that will also make connections on the database.

```js
router.get('/logs', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const logdata = await DatabaseController.getLogs()
    res.status(200)
    res.send({ logdata })
  } catch (err) { next(err) }
})
```

Normal requests are fine. However anytime I make a request that requires connecting to the database (GET/logs). I get the following:

> **Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first.**

DatabaseController implementation:

```js
const sql = require('mssql')
const config = require('config')
const dconfig = config.database

const addLog = async (options) => {
  const { text, isError } = options
  try {
    let pool = await sql.connect(dconfig)
    let request = await pool.request()
    request.input('message', sql.Text, text.trim())
    if (isError) {
      request.input('iserr', sql.Bit, isError)
      await request.query('insert into dbo.MApp_Logs (message, is_error) values (@message, @iserr)')
    } else {
      await request.query('insert into dbo.MApp_Logs (message) values (@message)')
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
  } finally {
    await sql.close()
  }
}
const getLogs = async () => {
  try {
    let pool = await sql.connect(dconfig)
    return await pool.request().query('SELECT * FROM dbo.MApp_Logs')
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
  } finally {
    await sql.close()
  }
}
```

The issue is that as is. I can't prevent my code from attempting to make multiple connections. Using a connection pool gives me the following error:

> "message": "Already connecting to database! Call close before connecting to different database.",
>       "code": "EALREADYCONNECTING"

How can I get around this issue? Is it possible to wait for a connection to close or use the existing connection?

Comment: Is it bad practice to create a new connection pool for each request?